# PYFPDF: Ajustar tamaño de una celda cuando existe una multicelda

Tags: python, fpdf

seré directo, quiero ajustar el tamaño de una celda de acuerdo al tamaño de la multicelda que se agranda conforme a la cantidad de palabras que tiene.[image: Bista de la multicelda y celdas]

He probado con el siguiente código que esta para FPDF2

```
from fpdf import FPDF
data = (
    ("First name", "Last name", "Age", "City"),
    ("Jules", "Smith", "34", "San Juan"),
    ("Mary", "Ramos", "45", "Orlando"),
    ("Carlson", "Banks", "19", "Esta es una prueba hecha con PYFPDF2, donde verifico que funcione el espaciado")
    )
pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font("Times", size=8)
line_height = pdf.font_size * 2.5
col_width = pdf.epw / 4.5

lh_list = []
use_default_height = 0


for row in data:
    for datum in row:
        word_list = datum.split()
        number_of_words = len(word_list)
        if number_of_words>2:
            use_default_height = 1
            new_line_height = pdf.font_size * (number_of_words/2)
    if not use_default_height:
        lh_list.append(line_height)
    else:
        lh_list.append(new_line_height)
        use_default_height = 0

for j,row in enumerate(data):
    for datum in row:
        line_height = lh_list[j]
        pdf.multi_cell(col_width, line_height, datum, border=1,align='J',ln=3, 
        max_line_height=pdf.font_size)
    pdf.ln(line_height)

pdf.output('table_with_cells.pdf')
```

Pero el resultado es el siguiente:[image: Resultado del código proporcionado]

Cambie los valores del tamaño de la letra pero no se lograba adaptar correctamente. Espero su ayuda para poder mejorar el código que tengo <3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿Qué tal?, te comparto el método que realice, espero que sirva
    `pdf.dosEnUno([['C',20, 5, '2000 ', 0, 0, 'C', 'N1'], ['MC', 20, 5, 'Texto de celda asdasdasdasdad asdasd asdasfasdasfa asdkjaskdjbajksdaksdnkasdnasd lkn', 0, 0, 'C'], ['MC', 30, 3, "laksdlkasd asdlasdp lkasjdlkasd jasldklaskdescripcion", 0, 'C'], ['C',20, 5, '2000 ', 0, 0, 'C', 'N1'],['C',10, 5, '2000 ', 0, 0, 'C', 'N1']])`

````
  def dosEnUno (self, dataRow):

        maxAltura = 0
        xMomento = 10
        yMomento = self.get_y()
        xMoment = self.get_x()
        cMulticelda = 0
        cCelda = 0
        listAncho = []
        listrowWith = []
        for i in range(len(dataRow)):
            calcW = (dataRow[i][1] * 190)/100
            # listAncho.append(dataRow[i][2])
            # print(listAncho)
            listrowWith.append(calcW)
            if dataRow[i][0] == 'C':
                print("Celda")
                if cCelda == 0:
                    self.set_y(yMomento)
                    self.set_x(xMomento)
                else:
                    self.set_y(yMomento)
                    self.set_x(xMomento)
                self.cell(calcW,  dataRow[i][2], dataRow[i][3], dataRow[i][4], dataRow[i][5], dataRow[i][6])
                cCelda = cCelda + 1
                xMomento = xMomento + calcW
            elif dataRow[i][0] == 'MC':
                print("Multi-Celda")
                # self.set_x(xMomento)
                if cMulticelda == 0:
                    self.set_x(xMomento)
                else:
                    self.set_y(yMomento)
                    self.set_x(xMomento)
                self.multi_cell(calcW, dataRow[i][2], dataRow[i][3], dataRow[i][4], dataRow[i][5])
                if(self.get_y()>=maxAltura):
                    maxAltura=self.get_y()
                print(self.get_x())
                cMulticelda = cMulticelda + 1
                
                xMomento = xMomento + calcW
        self.set_y(yMomento)
        self.set_x(xMoment)

        for w in range(len(listrowWith)):
            print(w)
            if(w==(len(listrowWith)-1)):
                self.cell(listrowWith[w],maxAltura-yMomento ,'', 1, 1, 'C')
            else:
                print(len(listrowWith))
                self.cell(listrowWith[w],maxAltura-yMomento ,'', 1, 0, 'C')
                ```
````

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).